# Show current tab URL in extension's popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to store the current tab url in the following `<input>` field:

```
<input type="text" id="pdurl" value=>
```

The code I wrote in `popup.js` is the following:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active : true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    var tab = (tabs.length === 0 ? tabs : tabs[0]);

    var activeTabUrl = tab.url;
});

document.getElementById("pdurl").innerHTML = var activeTabUrl;
```

I already have the `tabs` permission set in manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is totally wrong. There are some serious problems, which would have been easy to avoid checking the popup console for errors. Here they are:

1. First of all `chrome.tabs.query` is an **asynchronous** method. This means that the code is evaluated and queued to be executed; when it executes, the callback function (which you're specifying as second argument) is called and executed. This means that the last line you wrote will always fail because the variable you want to use still doesn't exist (the `query` function hasn't still finished working).
2. You are creating a useless (and wrong (because you're assigning an array to it)) variable inside the callback:  there's no need of your `tab` variable, because **querying an active tab in the current window always returns a single tab**, so you just need to use `tabs[0]`.
3. Your `activeTabUrl` variable is defined with the `var` keyword, which will make it private, and you won't be able to use it outside the function (which is what you're trying to do in the last line, althought it's still wrong).
4. In the last line you are trying to assign the variable you created in the callback function to the `innerHTML` of your input: this statement is so **wrong on so many levels** I don't even know where to start: first of all if you want to actually see something in the text input you have to **modify its `value`**; secondly: the variable is not defined; plus, the `var` statement in your assignment makes it syntactically wrong; fourth: even doing all of the three previous conditions right **you still are out of the callback**.

Stated the above, this is the correct code for what you're trying to do:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active : true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    document.getElementById("pdurl").value = tabs[0].url;
});
```

**I strongly recommend you to take a look at some JavaScript tutorial, and to check the console for errors* before asking questions like this one.**

<sup>＊ Errors in the popup of an extension are shown in the popup console, which you can open right clicking on the extension's icon and choosing "Inspect popup".</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am new to programming, so I need help at many levels. I used your code as follows                                                           chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
 function(tabs){
   
   var adurl = tabs[0].url;
   document.getElementById("pdurl").innerHTML = adurl;

 }
);
// How do I use the variable adurl with the current URL in another function?

Comment: you have to call the function you want inside the callback, passing that variable to it

Comment: It should be `tabs[0].url;` instead of `tab[0].url;`